# Как правильно заменить AsyncTask с более новым классом?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Я хочу переделать этот класс чтобы не было чего-то deprecated, но не особо получилось. Вот сам класс который я хочу переделать:

```
  private static class GetMovieTask  extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Movie>{
    @Override
    protected Movie doInBackground(Integer... integers) {
        if(integers != null && integers.length>0){
            database.movieDao().getMovieById(integers[0]);
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: вероятно, в текст вопроса стоит добавить некоторые подробности. для этого нажмите [edit].

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58767733/the-asynctask-api-is-deprecated-in-android-11-what-are-the-alternatives

Comment: Если база данных Room, читайте гайд: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/async-queries. И `AsyncTask`, кстати, вы неправильно используете, результат запроса в базу никак не используется и таск всегда выдаёт `null`, отсюда и проблема вашего предыдущего вопроса.

Comment: Спасибо. Исправил ошибку

Comment: Можно ответить как ответ чтобы я мог пометить как решение?